# Error with upgrade SDL Web 8.1.1 in Cluster Env

Tags: web8, upgrade, topology-manager, clustering

I am upgrading from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 to SLD Web 8.1.1 release within a clustered env.

1. Node 1 upgrade in Acceptance has been successful and is now considered "upgraded'.
2. Node 2 upgrade failed due to CMEnvID error below.

[image]

> TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID="TCMDBUser_DB" WEBSITE_ROOT_URL="http://SERVER.DOMAIN.com:80" AUTHENTICATION_TYPE="Windows" CORE_SERVICE_ROOT_URL="net.tcp://localhost:2660" ADDLOCAL="FeatureTopologyManager"'
>   [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:34]i000: Property 'CoreServiceRootUrl' of the item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' must be unique. Source of conflict: 'TCMDBUSER_DB'.

```
 [5E50:17C4][2017-01-27T13:19:05]i301: Applying execute package: TopologyManager, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8F6A09B9-1190-4359-B3B4-2BC8FBC15663}v8.1.1312\TopologyManager.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" TRIDIONHOME="E:\Tridion" DB_SERVER="DBSERVER" DB_TYPE="Oracle" DB_NAME="Tridion_Topology" DB_INTEGRATED="False" DB_USER="TTMDUSER" DB_PASSWORD="*****" WEB_ID="5" WEB_DESCRIPTION="SDL Web Topology Manager" WEB_IP="(All Unassigned)" WEB_PORT="81" WEB_HEADER="" ROU_NAME="CMSERVERNODE2\Topology Manager Users" ROS_NAME="CMSERVERNODE2\Topology Manager Service Users" ADMINS_NAME="CMSERVERNODE2\Topology Manager Administrators" SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_NAME="MTSUSER" SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN="DOMAIN" SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD="*****" TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID="TCMDBUser_DB" WEBSITE_ROOT_URL="http://SERVER.DOMAIN.com:80" AUTHENTICATION_TYPE="Windows" CORE_SERVICE_ROOT_URL="net.tcp://localhost:2660" ADDLOCAL="FeatureTopologyManager"

 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:34]i000: Property 'CoreServiceRootUrl' of the item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' must be unique. Source of conflict: 'TCMDBUSER_DB'.
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:34]i000: ExecuteError: e.UIHint=0
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:34]i000: ExecuteError: ErrorCode=-2147483648
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:34]i000: ValidateIis: prerequisite was detected: file 'InetMgr.exe' exists; sysnative=C:\Windows\Sysnative
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:19:53]i000: ExecuteError: user's action: Ok
 [5E50:17C4][2017-01-27T13:20:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
 [5E50:17C4][2017-01-27T13:20:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:20:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:20:18]i319: Applied execute package: TopologyManager, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
 [16F4:4EA4][2017-01-27T13:20:18]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *believe* this is a known defect on 8.1.1 installer, which got fixed in 8.5.

The work around involves using a different Topology Manager database for the 2nd install, then change the 2nd server to use the first one (and delete the second one).

One has to wonder though... why aren't you deploying 8.5 rather than 8.1.1?

Comment: Okay. I will try now

Comment: That worked @Nuno.. we started this upgrade process prior to the 8.5 release months ago